# HTML5 audio player shows time 0:00/NaN:NaN

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, nan

I'm trying to customize html5 audio player here and can't figure out what is wrong with duration. It shows NaN after adding duration, minutes and seconds in js file. Buttons are working fine already and audio is playing too.

JS:

```
var mytrack = document.getElementById('mytrack');
var playButton = document.getElementById('playButton');
var muteButton = document.getElementById('muteButton');

var duration = document.getElementById('fullDuration');
var currentTime = document.getElementById('currentTime');

var minutes = parseInt(mytrack.duration/60);
var seconds = parseInt(mytrack.duration%60);

duration.innerHTML = minutes + ':'+ seconds;

function playOrPause(){
    if(!mytrack.paused && !mytrack.ended){
        mytrack.pause();
        playButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/play.png)';
    }
    else{
        mytrack.play();
        playButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/pause.png)';
    }
}

function muteOrUnmute() {
    if(mytrack.muted == true){
        mytrack.muted = false;
        muteButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/mute.png)';
    }
    else{
        mytrack.muted = true;
        muteButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/muted.png)';
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <audio id="mytrack" preload=meta>
        <source src="audio/song.wav" type="audio/wav">
    </audio>
    <nav>
        <div id="defaultBar">
            <div id="progressBar"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button type="button" id="playButton"></button>
            <button type="button" id="muteButton"></button>
            <span id="currentTime">0:00</span>/<span id="fullDuration">0:00</span>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure that your minutes and seconds calculations are not returning any points. May be its just because of that. NAN is Not a Number.

Comment: Simply, `parseInt()` does not support sexagesimal notation like `0:00`.

Comment: var minutes = parseInt(mytrack.duration)/60; try this

Comment: parseInt(mytrack.duration)/60; didn't work.

Comment: Does it need to support sexagesimal since it's calculating minutes and seconds separately?

Answer (score 0):

The root problem with your code is that [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) is not as smart as you think:

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the
>   specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and
>   returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates
>   numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

```js
console.log(parseInt("11:59"));
```

As far as I know there's no built-in function to handle sexagesimal notation so you have a number of alternatives:

- Roll your own
- Find a third-party library
- Store actual numeric values into a variable, rather than parsing from/to text, and use text only for display purposes

Rolling your own should not be particularly difficult, feel free to ask for help if you opt for that.